Error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Ceiling' accepts this number of arguments
I'm trying to use the ceiling function in report builder power bi but it gives error each time I run the report.. and I get below error:
The 'Value' expression for the field 'Sheet1_Budget2' contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Ceiling' accepts this number of arguments.
The expression that I'm using is below:
=Ceiling(Fields!Sheet1_Budget.Value,1)
And if I removed the value 1, the ceiling function not reflecting!

What does it show when it's working? The CEILING function rounds up a number - it may not work if your field is text. You can try converting it to a decimal number with the CDEC function and then CEILING it - =Ceiling(CDEC(Fields!Sheet1_Budget.Value))

@Hannover Fist, even when I try to convert to decimal as below:
=CDec(Ceiling(Fields!Sheet1_Budget2.Value))
Nothing changes, the number still showing 9 instead of 10.. it should round up to nearest integer.

Did you try converting to CDEC before the CEILING with =Ceiling(CDEC(Fields!Sheet1_Budget2.Value)) . It should round up if there are any decimal places.

Yes, I have converted to CDEC then Ceiling =Ceiling(CDEC(Fields!Sheet1_Budget2.Value)).. the data I have is 13119 and I want it to show 13120

So your data doesn't have a decimal value? the data I have is 13119 and I want it to show 13120 . Ceiling will only round up if there's a decimal value.

I want to round to nearest 10ths and should does the work

Rounding up to the next 10 is different - you'd need to divide by 10 and then multiply after the Ceiling. =Ceiling(Fields!Sheet1_Budget2.Value / 10) * 10

Thank you so much @HannoverFist , it works now :)
